# Reusing result of ANY in SQL

Tags: sql, syntax

I've got a bit of SQL much like the following:

```
(...) where usr.USR_START > ANY (1,5,9) AND usr.USR_END < ANY (1,5,9)
```

Ultimately, I'd really like USR_START and USR_END to be compared to the same value, but I see no way to 'store' the result (the 'pick') of the ANY clause. As it is - as it should - it is just looking at *any* value from the list for each individually, and these do not need to match.

An obvious option to me seemed:

```
(...) where usr.USR_START > ANY (1,5,9) > usr.USR_END
```

but that kind of syntax just does not work in SQL. Is there any way to really tackle this?

Comment: Please Tag `RDBMS `you are using

Comment: @BHouse I'm not sure it is relevant? ANY is an ANSI-standard SQL keyword, is it not?

Comment: There might be RDBMS Specific functions that we could advice. Thats one reason why it is relevant.

Comment: @WeckarE. code is specific to database , although most functions are ANSI-standard

Comment: Maybe there is a different way to do this - but it's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Could you please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: I would say use `IN` operator for ANY (t-sql), will work for u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* your database system supports row value constructors, the cleanest I can think if is something like this:

```
declare @t table (USR_START int not null,USR_END int not null)
insert into @t(USR_START,USR_END) values (6,4)

select * from @t usr
where EXISTS (
    select * from (VALUES (1),(5),(9)) t(u) where usr.USR_START > u and usr.USR_END < u)
```

(Also using SQL Server syntax for the table variable)

Comment: That's clever! I think we can do this,